# Error with NDSolve when used for a nonlinear system of PDE's

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to solve the following system of Hamilton-Jacobi PDE's:
$ V_1,_t - 0.5 V_1,_x^2/(1 - 0.2x)^2 + V_1,_x(0.1x^2+0.03x+.0.01)/(1 - 0.2x)+0.03(x-0.5)^2-V_1,_x V_2,_x/(1 - 0.2x)^2=0$ 
$ V_2,_t - 0.5 V_2,_x^2/(1 - 0.2x)^2 + V_2,_x(0.1x^2+0.03x+.0.01)/(1 - 0.2x)+0.02(x-0.5)^2-V_1,_x V_2,_x/(1 - 0.2x)^2=0$ 
With terminal time conditions: $V_1(T,x)=0, V_2(T,x)=0$, where T is some final time and x is scalar.
I am not an expert, but my code is:

```
(* PDE *)
(* v1[x,t] v2[x,t] *)

pdeF = D[v1[x, t], t] - 
   0.5*(D[v1[x, t], x])^2/(1 - 0.2*x)^2 + (D[v1[x, t], 
      x])*(0.03*x + 0.1*x^2 + 0.01 - 0)/(1 - 0.2*x) + 
   0.06*(x - 0.5)^2 - (D[v1[x, t], x])*(D[v2[x, t], x])/(1 - 0.2*x)^2 == 0

pdeM = D[v2[x, t], t] - 
   0.5*(D[v2[x, t], x])^2/(1 - 0.2*x)^2 + (D[v2[x, t], 
      x])*(0.03*x + 0.1*x^2 + 0.01 - 0)/(1 - 0.2*x) + 
   0.04*(x - 0.5)^2 - (D[v1[x, t], x])*(D[v2[x, t], x])/(1 - 0.2*x)^2 == 0

solution = 
 NDSolve[{pdeF, pdeM, v1[x, 5] == 0, v2[x, 5] == 0}, {v1[x, t], 
   v2[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

> ```
> NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified 
>  for the direction of independent variable d. Artificial boundary effects may be present 
>  in the solution. >>
> ```

When I solve it for `t=[0,5]` everything seems to work, however when I use larger horizon e.g. `t=[0,10]` or greater, it just crashes. It makes the classic error sound of windows, and then all cells seem to have been reset like i just opened the program.
 
Any thoughts about that? Also, if anyone has another suggestion in order to solve this system in Mathematica or other software is more than welcome, as I need to get it done asap! 
Thank you all in advance, Cheers!

Comment: Boundary conditions are needed at `x = 0` or `x = 1.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the code to include the missing boundary conditions (chosen somewhat arbitrarily in the absence of additional information) that I mentioned in my comment above,

```
tmax = 10;
solution = NDSolveValue[{pdeF, pdeM, v1[x, tmax] == 0, v2[x, tmax] == 0, 
    v1[0, t] == 0, v2[0, t] == 0}, {v1,  v2}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}];
```

yields the result

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Through[solution[x, t]]], {x, 0, 1.2}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, t, v}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The `Method` specification is necessary to tell `NDSolve` that `t` is the temporal variable, because the boundary conditions would suggest otherwise.  Results are much less satisfactory, if `x` is assumed to be the temporal variable.

Comment: Firstly, a big thank you for your quick answer @bbgodfrey !! The results you present are pleasing and I can work on that, but still for greater values of `tmax`, I have the same original crashing problem.. In fact it works until `tmax=14`, then crashes. Have you witnessed the same or I've done something wrong?

Comment: @Jay  Works fine for me at `tmax = 25`, although it becomes unstable by `tmax = 50`.  Numerical instabilities are all too common in such calculations.

Comment: Theoretically though, the conditions on `tmax : v1(x,tmax)=0 and v2(x,tmax=0)` shouldn't be enough to solve the PDE numerically? As one can go at each fixed x and solve for all t using the conditions provided. Therefore we get the whole 3D surface..
I'm saying that because I believe that the boundary conditions on `x=0` affect the solution

Comment: @Jay  Without the boundary conditions on `x`, `D[v1[x, t], x]` and `D[v2[x, t], x]` cannot be determined at the boundaries.  So, if those boundary conditions are not specified, `NDSolve` sometimes quits and sometimes makes up the needed boundary conditions.  Neither is desirable.  Furthermore, boundary conditions have physical meaning.  Imagine playing a violin with the strings not attached at either end.